# Grep and Replace a string in a particular pattern

Tags: string, perl, sed, replace, grep

I want to add/replace a string in a file with in a particular pattern. Please refer below

```
"dont_search_this"   => {
    -tag => "qwerty",
    -abc_asd => [ "q/rg/dfg.txt",],
    -dependent_fcv => ["me_lib",  "you_lib",], 
    -vlog_opts => (($ENV{ABC_PROJECT}) eq "xuv")
      ? [ "-error=AMR", "-error=GHJ", "-error=TYU", "-error=IJK", ]
      : [] ,
},

"search_this"   => {
    -tag => "qwerty",
    -abc_asd => [ "q/rg/dfg.txt",],
    -dependent_fcv => ["me_lib",  "you_lib",], 
    -vlog_opts => (($ENV{ABC_PROJECT}) eq "xuv")
      ? [ "-error=AMR", "-error=GHJ", "-error=TYU", "-error=IJK", ]
      :[],
},
```

In above data, I want to add string "-error=all", in the line -vlog_opts in search_this paragraph only. Modified should be as follows

```
"dont_search_this"   => {
    -tag => "qwerty",
    -abc_asd => [ "q/rg/dfg.txt",],
    -dependent_fcv => ["me_lib",  "you_lib",], 
    -vlog_opts => (($ENV{ABC_PROJECT}) eq "xuv")
      ? [ "-error=AMR", "-error=GHJ", "-error=TYU", "-error=IJK", ]
      :[],
},

"search_this"   => {
    -tag => "qwerty",
    -abc_asd => [ "q/rg/dfg.txt",],
    -dependent_fcv => ["me_lib",  "you_lib",], 
    -vlog_opts => (($ENV{ABC_PROJECT}) eq "xuv")
      ? [ "-error=AMR", "-error=GHJ", "-error=TYU", "-error=IJK", "-error=all" ]
      :[],
},
```

Please help me in this.
Using perl is also fine.

Thank You very much!

Comment: "_Using perl is also fine_"  -- so what _are_ you using?  Or are you simply asking for someone to just write it for you?  Is this in a Perl program (it's valid Perl), or is it in a text file (as it says)?

Comment: This is an script file which needs to be modified(consider it as text).

Answer (score 3):

I can't help it but think that there's got to be a better way than editing the source code ... ?

Read the whole script file into a string and then follow the trail to identify the place to change

```
perl -0777 -wpe'
    s/"search_this"\s+=>\s+\{.*?\-vlog_opts\s+=>\s+[^\]]+\K/ADD_THIS/s; 
' file
```

(broken over lines for readability)

Notes

- `0777` [switch](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) unsets the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), so the file is "slurped" whole as one "line"
- the `/s` [modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) makes it so that `.` matches the newline as well
- the `\K` makes it so that all matches up to that point are dropped (not consumed) so they don't have to be (captured and) entered in the replacement part. So we literally add `ADD_THIS`
- Good information about `\K` is under "*Lookaround Assertions*" [in Extended Patterns in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) but keep in mind that it subtly differs from other lookarounds

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a perl data structure.

Any reason why can't just push `"-error=all"` into `$hash{search_this}{-vlog_opts}->@*`

Comment: This is an script file which needs to be modified(consider it as text)